# Touchpad Problem in 12.04

Tags: touchpad

I have installed 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on my Dell XPS 15z. The model came with a cypress trackpad for Windows 7. After installing Ubuntu, I realized the trackpad was not working at all. I tried installing Synaptics Touchpad in Windows, still it didn't work in Ubuntu. I searched on the net for similar problems but neither of them worked for me.

Here's what I did:

1. Edit the `rc.local` file to add the following lines in the file:

   sudo modprobe -r psmouse
   sudo modprobe psmouse proto-imps

   [Also tried proto-bare, proto-exps]
2. Tried to uncheck "Disable Touchpad while Typing" under Mouse Settings, but I could see no touchpad tab under that.

The command `xinput list` showed no touchpad. So maybe the problem is that touchpad is not detected at all?

Please guide me through this problem. I am a first time Ubuntu user and don't have much knowledge about it.

Are there any specific Ubuntu drivers for making Touchpad work?

Comment: both the trackpad's, synaptics and cypress, works perfectly fine on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Google up  project Sputnik. It seems that a new driver has been released.

http://bartongeorge.net/2012/06/20/sputnik-update-touchpad-driver-now-available/

Comment: Can you please add some detail to your answer? It's little more than a link to a third-party site, which means it may be deleted.